# A new performance review has been conducted by NX Gamer, apparently showing

Tags: gerunds, present-continuous

> A new performance review has been conducted by NX Gamer, apparently **showing** that the Xbox One version of the game is ... [Daily Express](http://www.express.co.uk/entertainment/gaming/618862/Fallout-4-Bethesda-DLC-update-Caps-exploit)

Could you help me to analyze the above sentence? what the part of speech of showing? Is it verb (present continuous)? or noun (gerund)?

I think it is present continuous:

> - A new performance review (has been conducted by NX Gamer) (**is**) apparently **showing** that the Xbox ...
> - A new review **is showing** that ...

Answer (score 1):

I agree, Shannak - the verb in the sentence is "to show", and it's in the present continuous tense.

Furthermore, I like the approach in your second bullet: simplifying the sentence down to its most basic components. That's often a *great* way to analyze a sentence's structure.